# Redirecting stderr of a Ruby script not working as expected

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, ruby, stderr

I have a command that I think is outputting to `stderr` because when I redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` I still get output printed to the screen.

However, when I redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` I also get output printed to the screen.

Further, when I redirect all output to `/dev/null` then it works as expected.

How can this be? Should `1>` and `2>` catch at least some of `&>`?

An example can be seen below:

```
$ HOME=/tmp/fakehome/ bundle exec bin/fullstop https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles
stderr output of 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles': fatal: destination path 'fake-dotfiles' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Error running 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles'
checkout dir already exists, use --force to overwrite
$ HOME=/tmp/fakehome/ bundle exec bin/fullstop https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles 1>/dev/null
stderr output of 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles': fatal: destination path 'fake-dotfiles' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Error running 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles'
checkout dir already exists, use --force to overwrite
$ HOME=/tmp/fakehome/ bundle exec bin/fullstop https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles 2>/dev/null
stderr output of 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles': fatal: destination path 'fake-dotfiles' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Error running 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles'
checkout dir already exists, use --force to overwrite
$ HOME=/tmp/fakehome/ bundle exec bin/fullstop https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles &>/dev/null
$
```

To replicate please clone my project:

```
➜  ~/D/w/tmp  rm /tmp/fakehome
➜  ~/D/w/tmp  mkdir /tmp/fakehome
➜  ~/D/w/tmp  git clone https://github.com/mbigras/mb-fullstop
Cloning into 'mb-fullstop'...
remote: Counting objects: 150, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (84/84), done.
remote: Total 150 (delta 49), reused 147 (delta 46), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (150/150), 24.06 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (49/49), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
➜  ~/D/w/tmp  cd mb-fullstop
➜  mb-fullstop master ✓ git checkout fix-git-logging-to-stderr
Branch fix-git-logging-to-stderr set up to track remote branch fix-git-logging-to-stderr from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'fix-git-logging-to-stderr'
➜  mb-fullstop fix-git-logging-to-stderr ✓ HOME=/tmp/fakehome/ bundle exec bin/fullstop https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles
stderr output of 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles': Cloning into 'fake-dotfiles'...
➜  mb-fullstop fix-git-logging-to-stderr ✓ HOME=/tmp/fakehome/ bundle exec bin/fullstop https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles
stderr output of 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles': fatal: destination path 'fake-dotfiles' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Error running 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles'
checkout dir already exists, use --force to overwrite
➜  mb-fullstop fix-git-logging-to-stderr ✓ HOME=/tmp/fakehome/ bundle exec bin/fullstop https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles 1> /dev/null
stderr output of 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles': fatal: destination path 'fake-dotfiles' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Error running 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles'
checkout dir already exists, use --force to overwrite
➜  mb-fullstop fix-git-logging-to-stderr ✓ HOME=/tmp/fakehome/ bundle exec bin/fullstop https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles 2> /dev/null
stderr output of 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles': fatal: destination path 'fake-dotfiles' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Error running 'git clone https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles'
checkout dir already exists, use --force to overwrite
➜  mb-fullstop fix-git-logging-to-stderr ✓ HOME=/tmp/fakehome/ bundle exec bin/fullstop https://github.com/mbigras/fake-dotfiles &> /dev/null
➜  mb-fullstop fix-git-logging-to-stderr ✓
```

Comment: `2>` should do the work, can you post the calling of the script

Comment: Hi @WissamAl-Roujoulah thanks for the comment, please see edit

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah added edit, please let me know if you'd like me to clear it up. I'm using a custom prompt, will change it to `$` if you're having trouble seeing where the prompt ends and the command begins :)

Comment: Interesting, i can't replicate your errors because i don't have ruby installed in my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a peculiarity of the Ruby logging library [methadone](https://github.com/davetron5000/methadone) used by that script. It behaves differently depending on whether standard output and standard error are terminals.

See the `initialize` method of [`cli_logger.rb`](https://github.com/davetron5000/methadone/blob/master/lib/methadone/cli_logger.rb). As described in the comments:

> A logger that logs error-type messages to a second device; useful
>   for ensuring that error messages go to standard error.  This should be
>   pretty smart about doing the right thing.  If both log devices are
>   ttys, e.g. one is going to standard error and the other to the standard output,
>   messages only appear once in the overall output stream.  In other words,
>   an ERROR logged will show up *only* in the standard error.  If either
>   log device is NOT a tty, then all messages go to +log_device+ and only
>   errors go to +error_device+

You may dispute the assertion that it is “pretty smart about doing the right thing”. A more sensible default for a logging module would log to stderr and ignore stdout.